# How to delete a specific index item in c++ using a for loop

Tags: c++, pointers

I currently have lastIndex equal to -1.  My goal is to loop through an array of students and values, using a "remove by id" function, remove that id and set of values, and replace it with the next value so there is no blank line in between.  After testing, I have found that last index is referencing the actual last index, but I need it to refer to the 3rd id which is the one I am trying to delete.  If I remove "Roster::lastIndex--;" it deletes the 5th(last)index and gives the following values in row 3 where it should delete. *Editor here will not let me post, but it is a set of diamond shapes with ? inside*.

```
void Roster::removeStudentById(string studentId) {
    bool success = false;
    for(int i = 0; i <= Roster::lastIndex; i++)
    {
        if (studentRosterArray[i]->getStudentID() == studentId)
        {
            success = true;
            if (i < numRoster - 1)
            {
                Student *temp = studentRosterArray[i];
                studentRosterArray[i] = studentRosterArray[numRoster - 1];
                studentRosterArray[numRoster - 1] = temp;
            }
            Roster::lastIndex--;
        }
    }
    if (success)
    {
        cout << studentId << " removed from roster." << std::endl << std::endl;

    }
    else cout << studentId << " not found." << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= Roster::lastIndex; i++)` this looks like [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Answer (score 0):

If your solution needs remove some items, try use `std::list` or `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` based on data nature, to achieve better performance!

for your code you can use `std::unordered_map` as

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Student> students;

void Roster::removeStudentById(std::string studentId)
{
    auto iter = students.find(studentId);
    if (iter == students.end())
    {
        std::cout << studentId.c_str() << " not found." << std::endl << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    students.erase(iter);
    std::cout << studentId.c_str() << " removed from roster." << std::endl << std::endl;

}
```

or use `std::list` as

```
std::list<Student> students;

void Roster::removeStudentById(std::string studentId)
{
    for (auto student = students.begin(); student != students.end();)
    {
        if (student->getStudentID() == studentId)
        {
            student = students.erase(student);
            std::cout << studentId.c_str() << " removed from roster." << std::endl << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
            ++student;
    }
    
    std::cout << studentId.c_str() << " not found." << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

If your data count bigger than some criteria such 10 or 20, `associated contaminates` as `map` and `unordered-map` get better `search` and `erase` performance than `list`.